# What's the best way to handle passwords in Ubuntu (Application + Browser PlugIn)

Tags: keepass

I'm switching **from Mac OS X to Ubuntu**. On OS X, i have 1Password as my Password Application. It comes along with Browser PlugIns to easily fill passwords to web forms.

On Linux, i've tested **KeePass X** and **KeePass 2**.

**KeePass X:** Is there a Browser PlugIn? I'm searching for hours, but nothing realy works.

**KeePass 2**: The Browser PlugIn for Firefox doesn't work (only for me?)

> Are there any other ways to handle passwords on Ubuntu with ease?

EDIT: It would be nice to have an open source application to store my passwords, which also has a PlugIn for Browsers. I want to avoid the system password manager or firefox password manager

Comment: In what sense do you need it as a browser plugin? KeePassX autotype works fine with any browser, it's just the responsibility of the user to ensure the focus is in the login box.

Comment: Sounds great, but what is autotype? How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This recipe should do the trick.  It provides an open-source alternative to [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/).

1. Install KeePass2 (sudo apt-get install keepass2).
2. If you have a KeePassX database (blah.kdb), convert it with the method over at http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-keepass2-on-ubuntu-natty/ as KeePass2 won't be able to open this DB natively.
3. Install [KeePassHttp](https://github.com/pfn/keepasshttp) using the method over at http://www.maketecheasier.com/integrate-keepass-with-browser-in-ubuntu/ to provide the integration between the desktop application and your browser.
4. Install [ChromelPass](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeipass/ompiailgknfdndiefoaoiligalphfdae) for Chromium / Google Chrome or [PasslFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/passifox/) for FireFox / IceWeasel.

Comment: Now KeePassX has a version 2 that uses the same format .kdbx. Also for integration with android you can use keepass2droid works nicely

Comment: Actually, [KeePassXC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeePassXC) is the way to go now.  For Android, I use KeePassDroid, but I'm sure either is fine.  I keep the databases synchronized with [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/personal/spideroak-one).

Comment: I've had a much better experience with keepass2droid (nice ui, finger print unlock, keeps track of file in dropbox...) but yeah, whatever works. I'll definitely give KeePassXC and SpideOak a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The adjective "best" turns this question into opinion, but there are indeed multiple ways to do it. In KDE all passwords are saved using their own keyring program. The alternative is gnome-keyring, which does the same thing. I do not know of a browser plugin for either application, but you can set firefox to do the same thing.

Go to Edit>Preferences>Security, then check "Use a master password". The dialog for master passwords should appear.

Answer (score 0):

If a separate password manager in/for the browser is acceptable,Then XmaksBookmarkSync can be used...
It saves and manages your passwords too along with bookmarks and tabs...
available for chrome and firefox both...